# How to track changes to Content WebView2

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, webview

It is necessary to track the link change in WebView 2. I have the following code in the VM:

**VM**

```
private Uri _myHtml;

public Uri MyHtml
{
    get { return _myHtml; }
    set
    {
        _myHtml = value;
        CheckUri(MyHtml);
        OnPropertyChanged();
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyHtml));
    }
}
```

**VMBASE**

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

**VIEW XAML**

```
<Wpf:WebView2 Name="webView"
                  Source="{Binding MyHtml, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" Grid.RowSpan="2"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
```

Alas, the breakpoint on "set" is triggered only when the "MyHTML" variable is directly assigned a value. But when you change the URL in WebView2, nothing changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options

1. Set the `Mode` to TwoWay, and remove the `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit`

```
Source="{Binding MyHtml, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

2. If you want to keep `Explicit` mode, you have to call `UpdateSource()` to update the bound property (i.e.`MyHtml`). This can be done by handling `NavigationCompleted` event like so..

In .xaml

```
<Wpf:WebView2 
    Source="{Binding MyHtml, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, Mode=TwoWay}"
    NavigationCompleted="WebView_OnNavigationCompleted" ..
```

In .xaml.cs

```
private void WebView_OnNavigationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.IsSuccess)
    {
        var bindingExpression =  
            webView.GetBindingExpression(WebView2.SourceProperty);
        bindingExpression?.UpdateSource();
    }
}
```

Note that in both options you need `Mode=TwoWay`.

Comment: Strange, but when changing the ViewModel I get an error: `System.NotImplementedException: "The Source property cannot be set to null."`

Comment: Add `if(webView.Source?.AbsoluteUri != null)` before `UpdateSource()`

Comment: It didn't help [Screen](https://imgur.com/a/mC1pumx)

Comment: It looks like the ViewModel changes first, then the View loses the MyHtml variable and this error occurs. It's just my guess

Comment: It's hard to tell.. this seems completely another issue!

Comment: I'm still studying MVVM, so it's not difficult for me to [share the project](https://github.com/efsfssf/VKSOVA---WPF-MVVM-Client-VK). For the test, I did hiding the WebView after launch (it was supposed to hide after logging in to the account). After the WebView is hidden, you can click the button to navigate to another VM, but then an error occurs due to the WebView. Navigation takes place from `LoginViewModel` to `ProfileViewModel`

Comment: I've tried to run the app on my device, but got an [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73817562/windows-application-runtime-error-incompatible-windows-build-this-demonstrat)..

Comment: Oh, sorry. Delete the question, I added the version check. I'll change the app to support older versions and send it back as soon as I'm done

Comment: I made changes and made a commit. You can download and try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248268/discussion-between-muhammad-sulaiman-and-nightnickname).